# How do you install an APK file it build from corona sdk in the Android emulator?

Tags: lua, apk, coronasdk

I am a pro user of corona sdk. And I build apk file with my own keyStore file. In that apk does not install in the android emulator?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use `adb`.  While the emulator is running, just run `adb install YourApp.apk`.

Comment: to install to the emulator, use `adb install -e YourApk.apk`

Comment: If all you have is an emulator running, and no device connected, it'll automatically install to the emulator without need for the '-e' option.

Answer (score -1):

1. Drag your .apk to Android's SD card.
2. Download an app named ASTRO.
3. In ASTRO, choose manage my file > folder you put ur .apk and open it.
4. Choose install.
5. WOW thank you ASTRO

Comment: He is using the emulator, where is he supposed to get astro?